# Apache startup error with symlinked configuration file with 777 permissions

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, configuration, symlink

Ubuntu virtual machine with Apache 2.4.7

I'm getting these errors:

`apache2: Syntax error on line 216 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/servername.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.`

Note: When I run `apachectl configtest`, it says `Syntax OK`

But there is such a file! In fact, Apache found it all by itself. Line 216, mentioned above, is `IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf`. So I guess it formed a shell expansion and got the list of conf files and then decided one of them didn't exist. Why?

As everyone knows, in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` are a bunch of symlinks to files in `/etc/apache2/conf-available`, created with `a2enconf`.

In my case, `servername.conf` in `conf-available` is itself a symlink, pointing to one of a set of my own configuration files (for apache and other services) for setting up virtual machines. For some reason, even though Apache is finding the symlink, it is reporting it doesn't exist. I don't see why it's a problem, since there is another symlink there that phpMyAdmin uses to link to its config files and causes no error.

One difference between the phpMyAdmin file and mine is that my file (and all of its parent directories) has 777 permissions. It is in a shared folder mounted from outside the virtual machine (shared with the Windows 8.1 host).

Does Apache have a problem with 777 permissions in config files?

Edit:
Here's `ls -l` output asked for in a comment.

`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/data$ ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/servername.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun 29  2016 /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/servername.conf -> ../conf-available/servername.conf`

And here's the symlink of the symlink:

`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/apache2/conf-available$ ls -l servername.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jun 29  2016 servername.conf -> /vagrant/config/servername.conf`

And here's the regular file:

`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/config$ ls -l servername.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 24 Jun 29  2016 servername.conf`

Comment: `ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/servername.conf`? And then `ls -l` whatever `servername.conf` points to? I don't understand how `servername.conf` could point to *"a set"* of configuration files.

Comment: @AlexP my mistake, I meant to say that it pointed to *one* of a set of configuration files. So, in conf-enabled, a symlink points to another symlink in conf-available, which points to the regular file in my own configuration directory.

Comment: And `ls -l /vagrant/config/servername.conf`? Please follow the symlink chain to the end. Remember that permissions and ownership on symlinks do not count, only the permissions and ownership on the final resolved file matter.

Comment: @AlexP I've added the details of the regular file at the end of the chain.

Comment: OK, final test; try to read that file as `www-data` (assuming that Apache HTTP Server runs as `www-data`): `sudo -u www-data cat etc/apache2/conf-enabled/servername.conf`.

Comment: @AlexP `www-data` is the right user for the server, and the file contents do get printed to the screen. `ServerName www.example.dev`.  Its purpose is just to establish the default ServerName to avoid the `could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name` error.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/396048/83838